# How to switch SQL Database at runtime with model

Tags: c++, qt

So I connect to a database like this:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("database.db");
db.open();

QSqlTableModel model;
```

This works fine the model points to the db connection. which is the default connection. See the constructor here:

```
QSqlTableModel::QSqlTableModel(QObject *parent = nullptr, QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase())
```

Now for some reason I want to set the database later in the program. So I tried this:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

QSqlTableModel model;

db.setDatabaseName("database.db");
db.open();
```

This does not work. If I check directly after model:

```
qDebug() << db.isOpen()
```

It returns true. The db is open.

I also tried then:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

QSqlTableModel model;

db.close()
db.setDatabaseName("database.db");
db.open();
```

But still the model does not show anything from the db.

So Short question:

I have a model in my app which points to a SQLDatabase. Do I have to create a new model when I want to switch to annother database?

Do I have to destroy the whole model and create a new one in its place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must create another model since the model is based on the database passed by the constructor.

Comment: Ah I saw that coming. So if I want to use this in qml I guess I have to expose both the database and the model and create the model dynamically with `loader` everytime I change database?

Comment: I understand the database is passed in `QSqlTableModel ` constructor, and cannot be changed. Is that correct?